# USB Insertion Causes System To Freeze, Crash, Then Reboot

Tags: usb, 20.04, freeze, crash

I have had an on going problem that I can't get to the bottom of for the life of me.

If my computer has been running for a while and I insert a USB stick into a port Ubuntu completely freezes, then reboots. This has happened with multiple USB drives so it's not one particular drive. Also, after the reboot if I insert the same USB stick it will work just fine and not cause any issues. However, if I wait a while and try again, the USB drive will then cause a freeze and hard reboot.

Below is a snippet of /var/log/syslog:

```
Aug  3 12:59:23 Chris-Ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4725]: (EE) client bug: timer event3 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-11ms), your system is too slow
Aug  3 12:59:31 Chris-Ubuntu systemd[4619]: gnome-launched-org.gnome.tweaks.desktop-9444.scope: Succeeded.
Aug  3 12:59:56 Chris-Ubuntu dbus-daemon[2477]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.162' (uid=1000 pid=16071 comm="/usr/share/code/code --no-sandbox --unity-launch /" label="unconfined")
Aug  3 12:59:56 Chris-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Aug  3 12:59:56 Chris-Ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[16071]: Warning: 'sandbox' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
Aug  3 12:59:59 Chris-Ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[7052]: [7052:0803/125959.991372:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(4927)] [.RendererMainThread-0x5c26e0b1e00]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
Aug  3 13:00:01 Chris-Ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4725]: (EE) client bug: timer event3 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-2ms), your system is too slow
Aug  3 13:00:01 Chris-Ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4725]: (EE) client bug: timer event3 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-15ms), your system is too slow
Aug  3 13:00:04 Chris-Ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4725]: (EE) client bug: timer event3 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-1ms), your system is too slow
Aug  3 13:00:04 Chris-Ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4725]: (EE) client bug: timer event3 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-14ms), your system is too slow
Aug  3 13:00:31 Chris-Ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4725]: (EE) client bug: timer event3 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-9ms), your system is too slow
Aug  3 13:00:31 Chris-Ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4725]: (EE) client bug: timer event3 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-22ms), your system is too slow
Aug  3 13:00:36 Chris-Ubuntu gnome-shell[7833]: [7834:7834:0803/130036.639713:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "chrome://newtab/". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/_generated_background_page.html (0)
Aug  3 13:01:31 Chris-Ubuntu PackageKit: daemon quit
Aug  3 13:01:31 Chris-Ubuntu systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
Aug  3 13:01:33 Chris-Ubuntu gnome-shell[7833]: [7834:7834:0803/130133.397873:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data. Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Aug  3 13:01:33 Chris-Ubuntu gnome-shell[7833]: [7834:7834:0803/130133.397925:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data. Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Aug  3 13:01:33 Chris-Ubuntu gnome-shell[7833]: [7834:7834:0803/130133.398204:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data. Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Aug  3 13:03:01 Chris-Ubuntu systemd[4619]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Aug  3 13:03:30 Chris-Ubuntu gnome-shell[7833]: [7834:7834:0803/130330.641225:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data. Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Aug  3 13:03:30 Chris-Ubuntu gnome-shell[7833]: [7834:7834:0803/130330.645550:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data. Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Aug  3 13:03:30 Chris-Ubuntu gnome-shell[7833]: [7834:7834:0803/130330.800509:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "chrome://newtab/". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/_generated_background_page.html (0)
Aug  3 13:03:49 Chris-Ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4725]: (EE) client bug: timer event3 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-11ms), your system is too slow
Aug  3 13:03:49 Chris-Ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4725]: (EE) client bug: timer event3 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-24ms), your system is too slow
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu systemd-modules-load[1188]: Inserted module 'lp'
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu systemd-modules-load[1188]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu systemd-modules-load[1188]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu systemd-pstore[1200]: PStore dmesg-erst-6856804976123969539 moved to /var/lib/systemd/pstore/6856804976123/dmesg-erst-6856804976123969539
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu systemd-pstore[1200]: PStore dmesg-erst-6856804976123969538 moved to /var/lib/systemd/pstore/6856804976123/dmesg-erst-6856804976123969538
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu systemd-pstore[1200]: PStore dmesg-erst-6856804976123969537 moved to /var/lib/systemd/pstore/6856804976123/dmesg-erst-6856804976123969537
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x1000157, date = 2020-04-24
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu systemd-sysctl[1202]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/all/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-42-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-038) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)) #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-42.46-generic 5.4.44)
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic root=UUID=cdbb6929-6f25-4075-b162-3a305f001078 ro
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu systemd-sysctl[1202]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/default/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x008: 'MPX bounds registers'
Aug  3 13:10:10 Chris-Ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x010: 'MPX CSR'
```

I inserted a USB at 13:05, however, there is nothing logged during that time.
I also am running a server motherboard, so I checked the mobo's internal event logs and again nothing is there at the time of the event.

Question:
What can I do to fix this or figure out what may be causing the issue? I have long running programs that take weeks to finish and a simple USB ruins everything. (I train deep learning algorithms)